# Interactive Brokers with IbPy, API connection not working on Mac OsX

Tags: python, api, interactive-brokers

I am having some issues with connecting with Interactive Brokers API with IbPy. I am trying to import:

ib.opt import Connection, message not working

and the error message I get is: 
from ib.opt import Connection, message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/ib/opt/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/ib/opt/connection.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/ib/opt/sender.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/ib/ext/EClientSocket.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IbPy-0.7.6_9.51-py2.7.egg/ib/ext/EReader.py", line 29
SyntaxError: cannot assign to None
```

My research has pointed me to these sites but I still cant not fix the problem. any help is much appreciated.

https://code.google.com/p/ibpy/issues/detail?id=16

System Specs: OSX 10.9.5 (Maverick) Python 2.7.8

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `$ pip install IbPy==0.7.2-9.00; python -c 'from ib.opt import Connection, message'` no issues here.

Comment: @achampion

I ran that but I still get the error:

SyntaxError: cannot assign to None

Comment: It seems the version of IbPy you have installed has this issue, install a previous version of IbPy, e.g. 0.7.2-9.00

Comment: Thank you so much IT Worked! but I had to use easy_install instead is all

Answer (score 2):

@achampion solved the issues

either use easy_install or pip and run pip install IbPy==0.7.2-9.00; python -c 'from ib.opt import Connection, message'